# Regex to replace directory to get only filenames in array

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I have the array containing several paths. I want to store in an array only the file names.

```
arr = ["/This/is/MyFirst/Path/file1","/This/is/MySecond/Path/file2","/This/is/MyThird/Path/file3"]
```

I'm trying to remove all except the filename with gsub, but I'm not sure why the regex I'm using is not working, since
when I run the code below, is not removing anything.

```
arr.each {|f| puts f.gsub( /\/\(.+\)*/, '')}
```

This is my test:

```
irb(main):172:0* arr = ["/This/is/MyFirst/Path/file1","/This/is/MySecond/Path/file2","/This/is/MyThird/Path/file3"]
=> ["/This/is/MyFirst/Path/file1", "/This/is/MySecond/Path/file2", "/This/is/MyThird/Path/file3"]
irb(main):173:0> arr.each {|f| puts f.gsub( /\/\(.+\)*/, '')}
/This/is/MyFirst/Path/file1
/This/is/MySecond/Path/file2
/This/is/MyThird/Path/file3
=> ["/This/is/MyFirst/Path/file1", "/This/is/MySecond/Path/file2", "/This/is/MyThird/Path/file3"]
irb(main):174:0>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Rather than using regex, why not just use [`File.basename`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/File.html#method-c-basename)?

Comment: @MxyL I agree with you..

Answer (score 2):

Why not ?

```
arr.map { |file_path| File.basename(file_path) }
```

Comment: Hello Arup, that option of basename works just fine! thank you. Even I have a solution, I remains thinking why the gsub with the regex used is not working. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You should not escape the parentheses. Otherwise they are treated as characters. Try the following

```
arr.each {|f| puts f.gsub( /\/(.+)*/, '')}
```

Comment: Hello miindlek, Thank you, doing as you said, I get all empty values. But I've tested in a regex tester and the regex works. I'm not sure why is not working here.

Comment: Which regex tester did you use?

Comment: I've tried the online regexpal.com to test the regex

Comment: I re-checked and this time works. It works like this: "arr.each {|f| puts f.gsub( /\/(.+)\/+/, '')}". Thank you!